# identity matrix and basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Is an identity matrix deliberately representative of the basis vectors of a given space? For example is a 3*3 ID matrix representing I - J - K hat basis vectors?

I haven't been able to find the answer to this question even though it is so basic, it's possible that im using the wrong terminology

Comment: Do you mean is the identity matrix constructed by making the columns the corresponding basis vectors for that space?

Comment: Hey yes that is what I meant, is this connection between the identity matrix's columns being composed of basis vectors from the associated graphic space a rule of thumb? Does it extend into higher dimensions (4+)?

Comment: Ask yourself: what happens if you make a change of the basis?

Comment: Taking standard basis, that is, $e_i$'s and then by making them columns can result in an identity matrix. Indeed, $e_i$' s form a basis. Note that for an $n$ dimensional space, $e_i$ is a column vector with ith component $1$ and rest of the $n-1$ components zero.